# SQL Query for self join

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Hi, I am having members table with above table structure. Here we can easily query MemberIDs by the column GroupID ..

Example... for GroupID=1, we will get the results

```
ObjectType    MemberID
-----------------------------
  user         1
  user         2
  group        2
  group        3
```

but, here my need is, I want to lists also the nested members( means members of the group member ....for group =2, group=3)

Expected result should be like this

```
ObjectType    MemberID
-----------------------------
  user         1
  user         2
  group        2
  group        3
  user         4
  group        3
  user         7
```

Can anyone help me to write query for this case?.

Comment: I'm not shure I understand your requirements. `Select * from Table Order by GroupID,MemberID` might look like your expected result.

Comment: It appears that `MemberID` can mean either a user ID (probably a reference to a different table's column) or a group ID (a reference to this table's `GroupID`). That is **not** a good idea as you will be unable to ensure referential integrity. Consider changing the design: user members and group members should be stored in separate tables (or, at the very least, in separate columns).

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a need for JOINs? You're dealing with 1 table itself if i'm not mistaken?

```
SELECT ObjectType, MemberID
From   Table
Group by GroupId, ObjectType, MemberID
Order by MemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to achieve this is to use a recursive `common table expression` or `CTE`
Something like this

```
;with cte as 
(
    select *, groupid as mastergroup,1 as level from yourtable 
    union all       
    select t1.memberid, t1.objecttype, null, cte.mastergroup, level+1
    from cte 
        inner join yourtable t1
            on t1.groupid=cte.memberid
    where cte.objecttype='g'
) 
select * from cte
where mastergroup=1
```

However, from your table structure it is unclear how the members of a group are defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a CTE here

```
    ;WITH tableResult (ObjectType, ObjectType)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT TD.ObjectType, TD.ObjectType
FROM yourtableAS TD   
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT TD.ObjectType, TD.ObjectType
FROM TaskDependency AS TD
INNER JOIN tableResult AS TR
    on TD.groupid= TR.memberid 
        and TR.objecttype='group'
    )

--then select from this cte
Select * from tableResult
```